# How to analyse means between two similar scales?

Tags: correlation

In a questionnaire I conducted for my dissertation, i asked respondents to rate the frequency (5 point scale from never to always) to which they resorted to certain unethical behaviour during their work. I also asked them to rate their acceptance of such behaviour using a reliable scale (5 point scale from Strongly Disagree to Strongly Agree).

Now, as expected, the mean scores of the self-admitted unethical behaviour is lower than the mean of the behaviour acceptance scale. Is there an appropriate statistical test to use in this case?

What test is there to prove that the behaviour acceptance scale is a good measure/representative of actual behaviour? Is correlation enough?

Comment: Your first question implicitly assumes the two scales are commensurable. This seems like a dubious assumption. Although a statistical test can show that two *numbers* differ, what would that possibly mean in this circumstance? It sounds a little like testing whether the speed of light is greater than the average weight of Florida oranges. Your second question seems less problematic, but it raises concerns about how *self-reported* and *actual* behaviors might fail to correspond.

Comment: I don't understand what the null and alternative hypotheses would be here.

Comment: Would it make any sense if I reported the correlation between them? Or should I just state that: The mean of the behaviour acceptance scale is higher than the mean of the self-admitted behaviour. This could imply that respondents may have underrated their admittance to the unethical behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking measures of [internal consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_consistency), which is commonly used in surveys. It measures the correlations between different items on the same test

[Cronbach’s Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha) is a commonly used method for this. See the links for details